# How to integrate COUNT(*)?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    $dbname = 'pdartist2';
    $table = 'artwork';
    $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder from artwork where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    $AID = $row['AID'];
    $ThumbFilePath = $row['ThumbFilePath'];
    $Title = $row['Title'];
    $DisplayOrder = $row['DisplayOrder'];
    $RecordCount = $row['Count']; {
            $ColCount = $ColCount+1;
        if ($ColCount ==5) {
            echo "<div id='clear'></div>";
            $ColCount = 1;
    }
    echo "<div id='thumb' onClick='window.location='gallery_detail.php?AID=AID';' title='Enlarge'>";
    echo "<div id='thumb_container'>";
    echo "<a href='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID'><img src='/$ThumbFilePath' title='Enlarge' alt='Enlarge' border='0'></a>";
    echo "<div id='name_spacer'>";
    ($ColCount);
    echo "<div id='thumbdesc'>$Title</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }       
}
    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

When I run this query it works as it should. The problem arises when I add the `COUNT()`. I need to have something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount from artwork  where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());
```

But the result from that query is not what it should be.

Comment: did you miss the `$` (Should be $AID) near: `gallery_detail.php?AID=AID`

Comment: Adding just count(*) makes very little sense. **What you want to count?**

Comment: What do you mean by "the result is not what it should be"? Please give us the exact error message or error description.

Comment: No, the count part is not working yet, that's what I'm working on. When I run the $result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount from artwork  where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());   I only get one record

Comment: @Theolddog Can be because where SCID = $SCID select just one row?

Comment: Dude, you will make things way simpler if develop a habit of asking help with *the actual problem* you face, not with your silly solution. this is considered much more useful behavior.

Comment: What is stored in the artwork table an what exactly do you want to query and count from it? Please give a more specific description of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to have the total row count, but COUNT(*) automatically groups them together.

Consider using a subquery.

```
$result = mysql_query("select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artwork WHERE SCID=$SCID) ResultCount FROM artwork  where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It must be work... i don't know who give him downvote...but he who give him downvote has no idea about mysql query +1

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way. Your essentially combining to totally differention data sets. These are really two queries and you should separate them.

Comment: Jens, I absolutely agree. The proper solution would probably be to use `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: Also simply using `mysql_num_rows` like Col. Shrapnel suggests should work as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder 
          from artwork where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
$scid_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

is it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the COUNT(*) you're returning the count of all rows, which results in a single row return.  If you want a count of total rows returned from your original query just use mysql_num_rows after your query returns.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
select AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount from artwork  where SCID = $SCID order by DisplayOrder group by AID
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` must be placed after `GROUP BY` and you should group by all non aggregate columns (e.g. except by `COUNT(*)`.