# Complex query and save it to a numeric variable

Tags: php

I need to query a group of images that I have give ID numbers to as AID (Art ID) and assign those particular numbers to a variable. The purpose is to go through the group with previous / next tags. So far, I have the group selected by this query:

```sql
SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artwork WHERE SCID=$SCID)
ResultCount FROM artwork
WHERE SCID = $SCID
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to group the $ResultCount by $AID. (Of course it should be in DisplayOrder, but that would be no issue.)

The difficulty is now to go back and forth with while staying inside the $ResultCount, especially since the $AIDs will not be in a numeric sequence.

Comment: i hope your variables are safe because you can inject sql there  ... super easy!

Comment: You have asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279287/how-to-integrate-count just 1 hour ago. Would you want us to do the whole app?

Comment: Hello Aurelio, I have been working on this for months. I have come a long way... but saved the most difficult for last. I made if work in Cold Fusion but PHP is a different ball game.

Comment: That is a great clue Book Of Zeus, know to figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Your count subquery returns a value that's based on all rows where SCID = $SCID but your outer query returns multiple values for AID.  Grouping on AID contradicts the count subquery.

If I understand correctly, you're trying to query the db to get counts of the number of rows having the same AID, something like this:

AID: aidval1
ThumbFilePath: "path/to/thumb"
Title: "mytitle"
DisplayOrder: displayOrderVal
ResultCount: # of rows with AID = aidval1

AID: aidval2
ThumbFilePath: "path/to/thumb"
Title: "mytitle"
DisplayOrder: displayOrderVal
ResultCount: # of rows with AID = aidval2

.
.
.

AID: aidvaln
ThumbFilePath: "path/to/thumb"
Title: "mytitle"
DisplayOrder: displayOrderVal
ResultCount: # of rows with AID = aidvaln

If that's right, try this:

```
SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, COUNT(SCID) as ResultCount
FROM artwork
WHERE SCID = $SCID
GROUP BY AID
ORDER BY DisplayOrder
```

As for preventing SQL injection - ensure that $SCID is type-checked and escaped as necessary.  If SCID is an INT or other numeric field, ensure the $SCID is a numeric type (ex: is_numeric($SCID)) before executing the query.  If it's alphanumeric, using mysql_real_escape_string (assuming you're using MySQL) is a good start.  Note that this is only a first-level of security and you'll probably want to read up on SQL injection attacks and their prevention to get a solid security model in place.

Comment: Thanks for your help DTJon, actually what I am trying to get the specific AIDs from the group I got with the count. This will allow me to go back and forth through the count. Take a look here, it may be helpful to see: http://www.pauldinwiddie.com/gallery_detail.php?AID=118&ResultCount=19

Comment: SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, COUNT(SCID) as ResultCount FROM artwork WHERE SCID = $SCID GROUP BY AID ORDER BY DisplayOrder This gives me a count of 1 when there should be 19 in the men group. But I think the group by is what I need.

Comment: When I try the GROUP with $result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artwork WHERE SCID=$SCID ) ResultCount WHERE SCID = $SCID ORDER BY DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error()); I get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE SCID = 1 ORDER BY DisplayOrder' at line 1

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following exactly what you want but if I understand correctly then when you do a query for rows where SCID = $SCID then that should return all the AID's you want and the number of rows returned would be equivalent to the COUNT you're grabbing?  If so, you could just use SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork WHERE SCID = $SCID ORDER BY DisplayOrder which returns all your AID values, and then use $resultCount = mysql_get_num_rows();.

Comment: @The old dog: If that's not what you're after please edit your original question to show a sample dataset from your db table and what values you would expect to receive for AID and ResultCount based on that sample data.